# Update Panel Problem

Tags: asp.net-ajax

we Have 3 dropdown in aspx page,  and also script manager and Update panel.  If there is some Post back date in the page meaning drop down selected, and i refresh the page, at that time i got this error.  After this error  Model Process bar is Continiousaly running on page .....

```
Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.
Source File: http://localhost:82/ScriptResource.axd?d=T9Asc1DcTyzRuacFr0N2k2Hx7n2rFYVCh_Ns52sZF_DvJbn_G6l6SwV-VCeFyQGysPMcj2gt3ABAuHBf80_jcnuIj6g3e6q683p7b1mULnA1&t=ffffffffae594486
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem...
Someone else had this problem with ModalPopup (of AjaxControlToolkit) migrating from atlas to ajax: http://forums.asp.net/thread/1705462.aspx.

****I've solved the problem setting ScriptMode property of ScriptManager to Release instead of Debug.****

I don't know why but it works....